# Modify array merge

Tags: php, json, mysqli

Hopefully I can explain this so that it's easy to understand. I'm struggling, so I'm coming here to hopefully get some help :)

I am combine/merging a few tables together. It seems to be working great but you will notice the line of code below.

> $records = array_merge($records, $records3);

I need to modify it so it has "source" included.

**For example:**

```
{
    "tags": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "video",
            "cssanimate": "flipInY",
             source:{
                "mp4": "1.mp4",
                "ogg": ""
            }
        }
    ]
},
```

**This is how it's displaying now. Which is wrong!**

```
{
    "tags": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "video",
            "cssanimate": "flipInY",
            "mp4": "1.mp4",
            "ogg": ""
        }
    ]
},
```

**Here is my code:**

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, username, volume, name, content, image, cssanimate, group_name FROM table_1 ORDER BY id ");
$result2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, username, volume, name, content, image, cssanimate, group_name FROM table_2 ORDER BY position");
$result3 = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, name, cssanimate, mp4, ogg FROM table_3 ORDER BY id ");


$records2 = array();
while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
    $records2[] = array('tags' => array($row2));
}

$records3 = array();
while ($row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc()) {
    $records3[] = array('tags' => array($row3));
}

// Place "table_2" and "table_3" in every 10th position
$counter = 0;
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $counter++;
    if(($counter % 10 == 0) || $counter==1 ) {
        $records = array_merge($records, $records2);
        $records = array_merge($records, $records3);
    }
    $records[] = array('tags' => array($row));
}


// Make is pretty
$json = json_encode($records, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);


......
```

Any help is kindly appreciated!

Comment: You might find [array_merge_recursive()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) or [array_replace_recursive()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php) helpful.

Comment: Thank you! Will take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll go nuts trying to use a built-in function for this.  It's too complicated to get it to do exactly what you want; I recommend building that array manually:

```
$result3 = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, name, cssanimate FROM table_3 ORDER BY id ");
$result4 = $mysqli->query("SELECT mp4, ogg FROM table_3 ORDER BY id ");
```

...

```
$records4 = array();
while ($row4 = $result4->fetch_assoc()) {
    $records4[] = array('tags' => array('source' => array($row4)));
}

$merged = array_merge_recursive($records3, $records4);
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you for the reply but I'm getting an error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ')'"

Comment: I think `$records4[] = array('tags' => array('source' => array($row4)));` was intended.

Comment: Thank you both for all your help so far! I'm getting an error "Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on array in" - is this cause by the $result = array_merge_recursive($records3, $records4); since "$result" has the same name as while loop? Here is the updated code https://codeshare.io/219lq7

Comment: Yep, sorry about those errors.  :(  Changed $result to something else; see edit above.

Comment: @FoulFoot thanks! I feel like this is so close! Here is the full updated code https://codeshare.io/2jEq4B but this is what I'm getting https://codeshare.io/5Nkwe8 Where is the source?

Comment: This: `$records = array_merge($records, $records2);  $records = array_merge($records, $merged);`  Also, remember to include the "ogg" in $result4 mysql_query above, unless you don't need it.

Comment: @FoulFoot I've updated the code https://codeshare.io/2jEq4B but now i'm getting https://codeshare.io/adlvAg  ... any idea? :) I really appreciate your help. I don't need "ogg" anymore.

Comment: I think there's something else going on here re: the actual data structure that isn't matching up, which is why `array_merge_recursive` is failing to merge the arrays.  Two comments: 1) in the expected output, you're going to have brackets around the "source" fields, because that's an array; 2) do you even need the "source" field to be an array, if all that's in there is the "mp4" subfield?  Just make the field "source mp4" and we can avoid all the trouble.  :)

Comment: Also, I think you're overwriting your $records variable there at the end.  In the `if` statement, you assign a value to the $records array every tenth time through the loop, which overwrites any previous value that $records held.  You'd need the concatenate brackets `[]` after `$records` if you intend to add them to the "master" $records array you're building.